# What should I do if all the migrations were deleted accidentally?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

EF Core has this warnning:

> Take care not to remove any migrations which are already applied to production databases. Not doing so will prevent you from being able to revert it, and may break the assumptions made by subsequent migrations.

But they have not tell us the solution when this accident happened ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try applying the migrations to a test database, then copy over the rows in the migrations table from there to the production db migrations table.